# Can not disable persistent_menu

Tags: laravel-5, bots, facebook-messenger-bot

I have enabled the persistent menu Command
php artisan botman:facebookAddMenu
, but now I would like to disable it and I do not find any command that disables it,
Please, can you help me to disable the persistent menu?

Answer (score 0):

If you send an **empty call_to_actions array** the menu will disappear.

It might need a few refreshes before the menu disappears (or delete conversation)

Comment: I tried sending empty call_to_actions. Grap API says "(#100) The parameter persistent_menu[0][call_to_actions][0][type] is required". Any other solution?